# How can I change the login URL for administrators?

Tags: forms

Is it possible to change the login URL for administrators, and use it only for them?

If another user comes, and logs in on www.example.com/admin, the system doesn't allow this.
If an administrator uses the normal login URL, the system doesn't allow this.

Comment: Before a user logs in, you wouldn't know whether he is a normal user or an administrator, right? How can you restrict access then?

Or would you want to just not allow "after" they attempt to login.

Comment: Agree with @AmarnathRavikumar. Before a visitor logs in, the user is just anonymous.

Comment: thanks for answers. I think when admin enter username and password and click login after that in database kontrol this if user_id=1 then system says there's no user on normal url www.example.com/users and also if users want to login on www.example.com/admin  after database kontrol if user_id!=1 system says theres no user but i can't do it on drupal how can i do this?

Comment: So, a user could log in using both the login URLs, but get an error if it uses the wrong one. This doesn't seem much user friendly. Apart that, what is the reason of having an administrator using a different URL, if then the login form is the same for both the normal users, and administrator users? After all, the login page just asks for a username, and a password. There isn't any security leak, by using the same login URL for all the users.

Comment: i think if someone find admin password but if they don't know the admin login url they can't able to login. Login url only admin know i think good for security. Am i right? or if any module like facebook set computer name(browser cookies) for login?